# Split data in a column to multiple rows

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel sheet where column A contains month and column B contains sales. 1 month can have multiple rows with different sales. I need to sum up the sales in every month. And then output in a new worksheet titled "Report" with each row for a new month.

```
I could have:
Month     Sales
Jan       15
Jan       5
Feb       3
Mar       4
Mar       8

I need to produce this:
Month     Sales
Jan       20
Feb       3
Mar       12
```

Comment: Can't you do this with a simple sum formula? And what have you tried so far, since SO is not a code writing service, please provide code you have tried. I would also suggest reading [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Pivot table are quite handy for this task but if you want your sum to update automatically, then you should use 'SUMIF'

Comment: @MamounBenghezal pivot table is still the way, instead using a fixed range for the source, use the `OFFSET` formula to get a dynamic range and use it as source, your pivot table will always be updated with all the data.

Comment: @Damian you can use a table as source data or the offset function to expand the range automatically, but you will still need to refresh Manually the pivot table to take into account the new data.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a pivot a table. Select the data range, go to Insert tab then press Pivot Table and OK (it will put the Pivot table into a new sheet by default). 
Put Month into Rows box and Sales into Values box.

Answer (score 1):

Have in mind that data appears in Column A (Month) & Column B (Sales). Range A2:B6.

[image]

**Steps:**

1. Select `D2`
2. **Go Data - Data Tools tab - Consollidate**
3. **Reference:** `$A$2:$B$6`
4. Press **Add** and ensure that the reference appears in **All references box**
5. **Use labels in: Left Column**
6. Press **OK**

[image]

**Results:**

[image]